# I get Error: CurrentRow.get returned Nothing When refreshing Datagridview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datatable, datagridview

Everything works normally when (Insert,delete,Update) data, but when using:

```
 dt.Clear()
 Form1_Load(sender, e)
```

to refresh DataGridView I got an error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

 System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CurrentRow.get returned
```

Any help please.

Comment: You are going to need to provide some context and likely some code here. We can't see your screen and have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: Take the relevant code out of `Form_Load` and put it in a separate Sub, maybe called `RefreshGrid`. Call this method from `Form_Load` and from the first block of code instead of calling `Form_Load`. You are not providing values for sender or event args when you call it from the first block. Thus the NRE.